# How Can I Associate A Foreign Key Of A Django Class Model Field To A Parent's Class Field

Tags: python, django

I am creating a question and answer django model where i want to set the correct answer to an option on the same class

Essentially I Want To Do Something Like This

```
class Question(models.Model):
   question = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   options  = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')
   correct_answer = models.ForeignKey('self.options',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Unfortunately I'm Getting Errors From Django.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just point the foreign key to the same model? Like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
   question = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   options  = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')
   correct_answer = models.ForeignKey('Answer',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Yes I Could But Still It Wouldn't Solve My Problem.
I Don't Want The Whole Model But Instead I Want A Particular Field Of That Model
Which Is The Options Field